# How do I run multiple Selenium tests with different required capabilties

Tags: unit-testing, testing, selenium

I want to run the same test code:

e.g.

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
element.sendKeys("mysql excel 2013");
element.submit();

// Check the title of the page
System.out.println("Page title is: " + driver.getTitle());

// Google's search is rendered dynamically with JavaScript.
// Wait for the page to load, timeout after 10 seconds
(new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
    public Boolean apply(WebDriver d) {
        return d.getTitle().toLowerCase().startsWith("mysql");
    }
});

// Should see: "cheese! - Google Search"
System.out.println("Page title is: " + driver.getTitle());
// Close the browser
```

With different capability configurations

```
DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
capability.setVersion("15");
capability.setCapability("flash", "11-4");

RemoteWebDriver driver =  new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://192.168.1.22:4444/wd/hub"), capability);
```

Chrome

```
DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
capability.setVersion("21");
capability.setCapability("flash", "11-4");

RemoteWebDriver driver =  new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://192.168.1.22:4444/wd/hub"), capability);
```

What is the best way to do this without just creating multiple instances with different capabilitilies? Is there a concept provided by Selenium for doing this ?

Or would I "simply" use some kind of looping construct to loop over?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For achieving this you should go for parameter passing concept using testng

**TestNg Suite**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
    <suite thread-count="2" name=MyTestSuite" parallel="tests">

      <test name="RunInFirefox" preserve-order="false">
       <parameter name="version" value="8"/>
       <parameter name="browser" value="firefox"/>
       <parameter name="flashVersion" value="11.2"/>
        <classes preserve-order="true">
           <class name="com.test.TestCase1"/>
           <class name="com.test.TestCase2"/>
           <class name="com.test.TestCase3"/>
        </classes>
      </test>

     <test name="RunInChrome" preserve-order="false">
       <parameter name="version" value="21"/>
       <parameter name="browser" value="chrome"/>
       <parameter name="flashVersion" value="11.2"/>
        <classes preserve-order="true">
           <class name="com.test.TestCase1"/>
           <class name="com.test.TestCase2"/>
           <class name="com.test.TestCase3"/>
        </classes>
      </test>
    </suite>
```

**TestNg TestCase**

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;

public class ExampleTestCase {

private static WebDriver driver;

@Parameters({"browser,version,flashVersion"})
@BeforeClass
public void beforeClass(String browser,String version,String flashVersion) 
{
    driver=getDriverInstance(browser,version,flashVersion);
    }

@BeforeTest
public void beforeTest() 
{

}
@Test
public void f() 
{
    //your test code here
}

@AfterTest
public void afterTest() 
{

}

@AfterClass
public void afterClass() 
{

}
```

}

**getDriverInstance** method implimentation

```
public static WebDriver getDriverInstance(String browser,String version,String flashVersion)
{
    WebDriver driver=null;
    if(browser.equals("firefox"))
    {
        DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
        capability.setVersion(version);
        capability.setCapability("flash", flashVersion);
        driver =  new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://192.168.1.22:4444/wd/hub"), capability);
    }
    else if(browser.equals("chrome"))
    {
        DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
        capability.setVersion(version);
        capability.setCapability("flash", flashVersion);
        driver =  new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://192.168.1.22:4444/wd/hub"), capability);
    }
    return driver;
}
```

Comment: so TestNG will take care of executing the Test multiple times with the different parameters ?

Comment: so i take a few things from your answer: 1. there is no native selenium way of doing it 2. you do it with some kind of loop where you propose TestNG

Comment: The same thing you can do using selenium grid also but, there also you need impliment some mechanism to run cases in parallel or passing test cases to different nodes (You should start the nodes by specifying your customizations)

See this link : http://rationaleemotions.wordpress.com/2012/01/23/setting-up-grid2-and-working-with-it/

Comment: thx, i already have a skript starting up machines - starting selenium node with custom configuration, now i have to look how to call the machines. , If have to create an own RemoteWebDriver Object for each machine donÄt i ?

Comment: No changes needed for above script. Any way you are instantiating driver using RemoteWebDriver only. In Grid concept hud will take care of distributing test cases to specified nodes.

Comment: i now have a modified script where you are able to define multiple capabilities, over which i iterate and for each capability a RemoteWebDriver is instanciated